# TYPO3: Access denied to database after moving installation

Tags: exception, typo3, typo3-10.x

I have migrated successfully my TYPO3 v10 site under mampp. Now I get this exception:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException An exception occurred in driver: Access denied for user 'dbxx'@'localhost'

My configuration entry is the following:

```
'DB' => [
        'Connections' => [
            'Default' => [
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'dbname' => 'mysite_f10',
                'driver' => 'mysqli',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'password' => 'root',
                'tableoptions' => [
                    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                    'collate' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                ],
                'user' => 'root',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Is it possible, that TYPO3 stores still my old database values in a cache? And if, how can I clear my cache manually?

Comment: if the login data are not located in the LocalConfiguration, you should look into your .htaccess or AdditionalConfiguration. There, you might have some created  Environment variables and those will be used for the connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Database credentials are not cached anywhere. I assume that you changed the values in `LocalConfiguration.php`. You should check your installation if there is a file called `AdditionalConfiguration.php` in the same directory as `LocalConfiguration.php`. All values in that file overwrite values from `LocalConfiguration.php`.